TO find word count file by file
Is it possible to determine the number of times a particular word appears in multiple files - file by file - using grep
the "-c" option but this returns the number of matching lines the particular word appears in - and would nto work as a line may contain multiple instances of the word
For example :
File A.txt:
some 12345 words and risk and risk
File B.txt:
and 12345 then another risk
File C.txt:
dummy words
I would run grep -l "12345" *.txt | xargs grep ?????? risk -
Expected output
A.txt:2
B.txt:1

do you want all occurrences of risk or just the ones that appear on the lines that contain 12345 ?

Something like this would count the words
awk -v w=risk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)if($i==w)f[FILENAME]++} END {for(n in f)print n,f[n]}' A.txt B.txt
A.txt 2
B.txt 1


With GNU awk for multi-char RS, ENDFILE, and \s shorthand for [[:space:]]:
$ awk -v RS='\\s+' -v word='risk' '$0==word{cnt++} ENDFILE{if (cnt) print FILENAME, cnt; cnt=0}' {A,B,C}.txt
A.txt 2
B.txt 1

You can easily transform that to count occurrences of all words in each file if you like:
$ awk -v RS='\\s+' '{cnt[$0]++} ENDFILE{for (word in cnt) print FILENAME, word, cnt[word]; delete cnt}' {A,B,C}.txt
A.txt some 1
A.txt words 1
A.txt risk 2
A.txt and 2
A.txt 12345 1
B.txt risk 1
B.txt another 1
B.txt and 1
B.txt then 1
B.txt 12345 1
C.txt words 1
C.txt dummy 1

